# Logo between two texts

Tags: titles

I am trying to create a title page such that the logo is on the top on the left of the logo I will write the University/department in English on the write of the logo I will write University/department but in another Language

So it will look like that

University              Logo          university

department

Comment: Welcome to the site.  A picture is worth 1000 words.  Better still, some code of what you have tried would also be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

There are many solutions for your problem but it's hard to know which one would work best for you without more details. Below is a sketch of a possible solution that uses the `titlepage` environment for the title page, `\vfill` to distribute material vertically and `\centering` to center material on the page.

For the real logo you would use `\includegraphics` from the `graphicx` package.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\logo{\fbox{\rule{2cm}{0pt}\rule[-1cm]{0pt}{3cm}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}\Large
    \vfill
    \centering
    \textbf{\huge University}\hfil\logo\hfil\textbf{\huge University}
    \vskip2cm
    Department Department
    \vfill
    \vfill 
    \vfill
\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

[image]